# CouchDB replication from per-user databases to master database

Tags: couchdb

I've that system arch: master database named `master` and users databases named `user1` and `user2`. I'm replicating a document from master database to both `user1` and `user2` dbs. Then users separatelly modify that document in their DBs (for example user1 adds `tags:[1, 2]` and user2 adds `tags:[3, 4]` fields). Now I'd like to replicate from users databases back to master and merge newly added `tags` field so its result into `tags:[1,2,3,4]`. Also, I may probably need to run some logic on replication that will make resulted tags to be `tags:[1,2,4]`.

What is the right approach?

Comment: You should manage conflicts: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication_and_conflicts

Comment: Are the tags inside of the user documents or their own documents?

Comment: tags are field inside FEED document which is just {_id: 'xxx', name:'yyy', tags:[])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say how you might want to drop tag "3" in your final result, so it's hard to give a full answer.

There is a lot of good information about various ways to handle just this sort of scenario in the CouchDB Documentation. [Designing how you store the data](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/best-practices/documents.html#designing-an-application-to-work-with-replication) and how you [use the stored data to resolve conflicts](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/replication/conflicts.html) which includes the following "Suggested code to fetch a document with conflict resolution"

1. GET docid?conflicts=true
2. For each member in the _conflicts array:
   GET docid?rev=xxx
   If any errors occur at this stage, restart from step 1.
   (There could be a race where someone else has already resolved this
   conflict and deleted that rev)
3. Perform application-specific merging
4. Write _bulk_docs with an update to the first rev and deletes of
   the other revs.

It also notes "This could either be done on every read (in which case you could replace all calls to GET in your application with calls to a library which does the above), or as part of your sweeper code."   And it goes on to give a full example in Ruby.

Does that answer all your questions?

Answer (score 3):

This is simply solved with replication + conflicts. Have a master external process that checks for conflicts, merges the tags & then writes the new document.